# Fill data in excel sheet from master list from another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, libreoffice-calc

I have data in two separate excel sheet in single file.

In the first sheet, I have two columns...like this

Sheet1

[image]

In the second sheet, I have one of the column which is same as Name in Sheet1. However, it does not have second column where I want to bring the value referring to the sheet 1.

Here is the second sheet.

[image]

Here in second column, i.e. Color I want to bring the value from first sheet.

I am using Libreoffice but can use excel as well. Pls suggest how I would do this in excel / libreoffice.

Comment: `VLOOKUP()` is what you're looking for (in Excel, I assume that LibreOffice has something similar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for Excel...

So use sheet one as the reference sheet. Sheet two as the one you want to fill.

In B2 on Sheet 2 enter this formula:

```
=vlookup(A2,Sheet1!$A$1:B$6$,2,FAlSE)
```

Then drag down.

This is assuming that your reference in sheet one is in columns A and B and goes from rows 1 to 6.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

One of the easier ways to do this would be to use VLOOKUP.  So this requires 4 inputs:

1. The value you are searching for
2. The array you are searching in
3. The column where the value you want to return is in
4. "FALSE" to list if you want an exact match between the value you are searching for and the array you are searching in.

So in your example, we will use the worksheet where you only have the Names listed as the worksheet you are putting the formula, so something like this in B2:

=VLOOKUP(A2,sheet2!$A$2:$B$6,2,FALSE)

So this would lookup the value you show in worksheet 1 cell A2.

Then go to workbook 2 and match that value with what is in A2:A6.

Then lookup what is in column 2 for your answer.

And return what is in column 2 only if worksheet 1 cell A2 and something in worksheet 2 range A2:A6 is an exact match.

There are other ways, but for your example, this should be easiest in EXCEL.  This only works if the value you are searching for is to the right of the value you are looking up.  If you need to go to the left, INDEX/MATCH would be better (but not required here).

Hope this helps!

JW